# A good source code editor

Tags: gratis, linux, software-development, text-editor

I want a source code editor with the following features

- Must support C, C++, Java, Ruby Python and Django and its HTML templating language
- Must not be very heavy, avg. memory usage 100M
- The editor must be good looking, have nice fonts and easy to use (much like elementary OS or macOS)
- Must be avaliable for Ubuntu and Arch
- Also it must auto-complete for functions, modules names and variables for the standard library at least

Must be free-of-charge or have a free student license avaliable. May or may not be open source.

Comment: Hi, about that memory limit: do you really mean 100M?   If so, the answer is trivial: Eclipse.   If you mean 100K, are you sure  you need to keep it that small?   That's a hard target to hit - even vi is often bigger.

Comment: I am talking about RAM usage not HDD usage...

Comment: I'm talking about RAM usage too.  Have you ever tried Eclipse?  It's a full-blown IDE, but the SCE part is pretty solid.  And the footprint is generally way under 100M for editing in my experience - of course, if you're also running/debugging, it goes up.

Comment: Yeah I have used Eclipse one or two times but I has too many dependencies and maintaining an IDE is useless considering I use JetBrain's IDEs most of the time. I need a editor for small time editing solving CP problems

Answer (score 3):

The full-featured [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s may run in that memory range:

- [JetBrains IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)
- [Apache NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/index.html)
- [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/)

## Atom

**Update:** [Atom will retire](https://www.ghacks.net/2022/06/09/githubs-atom-text-editor-will-be-retired-in-december/) near the end of this year, 2022-12-15.

For simpler text editor apps, [Atom](http://www.Atom.io/) is all the rage now. See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)).

A local desktop app but interestingly built of JavaScript and web technologies. Full-featured, right out of the box, but also quite hackable if you so desire.

[image]

## jEdit

This Java-based editor was once my workhorse favorite, [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/).

Supports a couple hundred languages including Django.

Comment: Isn't NetBeans made by Oracle???

Comment: @JøêGrèéñ https://netbeans.org/community/apache-incubator.html

Comment: Atom is almost dead

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) runs on multiple [platforms](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) including Ubuntu.  It’s lightweight and meant to be an editor, not, a full blown IDE.

**Features**:

- IntelliSense
- Debugging
- Built-in Git
- Many 3rd party [extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/#hundreds-of-extensions)

It’s free and can be customized with themes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at Geany - open source, cross platform (Linux, OS X, Windows).  Supports all of the languages you mention, syntax hilighting, a console window to work in, and compile/build buttons that can be customized to use your build chain.  It is more of a super light and configurable IDE than plain text editor...

Answer (score 0):

Give **CudaText** a try. It is open source, free. All items are done in it, except one item:

"Also it must auto-complete for functions, modules names and variables for the standard library"-- this is syntax dependant. For Python it's supported via plugin "Python Intel". For other syntaxes not supported.

Many features - in plugins (Addon Manager).

[image]

Comment: Does it supports Jinja or Django Template Language???

Comment: @Joe, Yes, it has lexers Jinja and "HTML Django" in Plugins/ Addon Manager.